Completely uninstall an application on Windows using powershell
I am trying to uninstall osquery and other apps on some problematic devices and want to use powershell to do so. I have thousands of computers I need to apply this to so manually uninstalling is not an option. Is there a Windows utility that does deep uninstall like TotalUninstall or Revo Uninstaller that can be scripted with power shell? I already have a script that uses the basic powershell commands to uninstall the applications but it doesn't work consistently. I also use the WMI system to uninstall the package and it's not working on all devices.
Some research I've done:
https://linuxhaxor.net/code/uninstall-software-using-powershell.html
https://www.technewstoday.com/powershell-uninstall-software/
https://github.com/pldmgg/ProgramManagement
https://github.com/avwrgit123/Windows-Install-and-Uninstall-Software-Script
https://github.com/ShadowWhisperer/AppExorcist/tree/main
I'd like to explore all options for uninstalling applications on Windows using powershell. In particular if I can replicate the advanced uninstallers and how they work with a powershell script or find an uninstaller that can be scripted with powershell.

It varies with every application. If it's an msi you can do get-package *app* | uninstall-package. For programs something like cmd /c $_.metadata['uninstallstring'] /s.

I am only concerned about MSIs. I've observed that sometimes the MSI installer is missing and the uninstall prompts you to provide it. Sometimes the service is not stopped and removed after the uninstall. Or the MSI is completely not found and the app can't be removed.
